# How to fetch list of tables in database using HibernateDaoSupport?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

Here I have added my code. Issue occurs in try block while I am trying fetch list of tables.

Database is MySql 
Exception is  : **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!**

```
public class DBOptimizationDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport {

private static final Log log  = LogFactory.getLog(DBOptimizationDAO.class);

public void optimizeAdapter(String year)
{
    List<com.ecw.adapterservice.beans.TransactionInbound> transactionInboundList = null;
    StringBuilder queries = new StringBuilder();
    try {       
        transactionInboundList = (List<com.ecw.adapterservice.beans.TransactionInbound>)super.getHibernateTemplate().find("from TransactionInbound where inboundTimestamp < '" + year+ "-01-01'order by 1 desc limit 2");

        //  Check if archive table exist or not
        List<Object> inboundObj = getHibernateTemplate().find("SHOW TABLES LIKE transaction_outbound");
        List<Object> outboundObj = getHibernateTemplate().find("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'transaction_outbound_archive'");
```

Comment: What issue occurs in the try block?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!

Comment: Please add this piece of information to the question, ideally including the stacktrace.

Comment: Sure buddy. Now let's focus on question please.

Comment: Please consider reading to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I just tried to help imroving your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve could also be of help.

Comment: Sure thanks for that.

Comment: What database do you have under Hibernate?

Comment: database I use is mysql

Comment: You should not be using Hibernate if you're still thinking in terms of tables and SQL.  ORM is intended to let you use objects and forget about the relational model.  You're doing it wrong if those two tables don't make to a sensible object.

Comment: Sounds great. But then how would I get the list of tables in database?

Answer (score 0):

The `HibernateTemplate::find` expects a HQL query in the string parameter and you are passing a native statement. You can do native stuff (queries, statements, etc) using the `Session` object returned by [`HibernateTemplate::getSession`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#getSession--). To pass a native select query you then have `Session::createSQLQuery`

**BUT** do you really want to rely on database specific code to do this? There is **a more elegant way to do it** by using [`DatabaseMetaData::getTables`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780284/how-to-get-all-table-names-from-a-database). And you can get an instance of DatabaseMetaData [from a callback method of your HibernateTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342853/2743585).

Try this:

```
        Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        if(!session instaceof SessionImpl){
                    //handle this, maybe throw an exception
                }
        else {
            Connection con = (SessionImpl)session.connection();
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Please show me the code to get session from hibernatetemplate.