# How to validate database schema programmatically in Hibernate 5 with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327423/how-to-validate-database-schema-programmatically-in-hibernate-with-annotations) is about validating DB schema with older versions of Hibernate. I try to update this code with Hibernate 5.

Here is a first naive implementation:

```
public boolean isSchemaValid() {

    // EntityManagerFactory is autowired by Spring
    SessionFactory sessionFactory =
            entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
            sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry();

    try {
        new SchemaValidator().validate(
                new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata(),
                serviceRegistry);
        return true;
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Without much surprise it doesn't work since it returns true even when the schema is not valid (the schema is different or does not exist). I guess this is because the `Metadata`object passed to the `new SchemaValidator.validate(...)` method is not complete, e.g. does not contain the `@Entity`bean definitions. However I have a hard time finding out or to call this validate method properly.