# Hibernate schema validation with multiple data sources in multi tenant(separate databases) application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I have a Spring Boot app with multi-tenancy enabled with separate database for each tenant. I also have a database which holds tenant datasource information and another database for user data. All tenant databases have the same schema.

Datasource information is loaded at app start and kept in a map for `AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl` implementation to use.

I'm using Liquibase and I've set it up so that it updates the tenant databases with each run of the app, and now I'm trying to enable `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` for each of the tenant databases but not for the user or datasource databases.

The idea is for the workflow to look like this: change app and db->liquibase updates db->hibernate validates the changes.
Here's my hibernate configuration right now:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(
            DataSource dataSource,
            MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
            CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl
    ){
        Map<String,Object> jpaPropertiesMap=new HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER,multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER,currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL,true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL,true);
        //jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO,"validate");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em=new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.klikfin.*");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
        return em;
    }
}
```

When I enable `jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO,"validate");` it only validates the default datasource database.

### How would I enable it for specific databases only?

Comment: Basically same issue for me (though I'm using schema-based multi-tenancy).  All the proposed solutions I've found elsewhere don't seem to work anymore, since Hibernate changed the SchemaValidator class to an SPI.  e.g. this is no longer a valid solution I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464978/validate-schema-programmatically-using-hibernate